# Submit a form and get a JSON response without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, forms

I have a simple HTML form like this:

```
            <div class="border-little text-center grey">
                <form action="https://www.THIS IS MY URL.php" method="get">
                    <input name="player" id="player" value="1" class="hidden">
                    <label for="number">Enter a number</label>
                    <input type="text" id="number" name="number" placeholder="">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </div>
```

**The operation is as follows:**
The player enters a number, and the server answers using a JSON format.

**My issue:**
When I press "submit" My webpage leaves and redirects to the server page display a JSON formatted answer.

**What I want to do:**
I want to stay on my page and be able to receive the answer in JSON format and display them below my form instead of being redirected to the server page.

**More details:**
example of JSON answer I get from the server:

```
{"guess": "lower"}
```

I cannot use any kind of JavaScript library so JQuery is forbidden.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery  ajax is one of those things that are significantly less verbose using a help library.

Comment: Add named iframe tag below the form and submit the form to this iframe by name. <form action="https://www.THIS IS MY URL.php" method="get" target="myframe">... <iframe name="myframe"></iframe>

Comment: @AlexS. the iframe is a really good Idea thank you a lot it works, by the way do you have an idea how to check the answers and do something if the number in the right one like when I receive {"guess": "YouWon!"}

Comment: To process json from iframe in main window get it contents by the following way: var myframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0], content = (myframe.contentDocument || myframe.contentWindow.document).textContent, json = JSON.parse(content);

Comment: I am sorry @AlexS. I don't understand what you did on the comment above, can you please give me more details ?

Comment: I got : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of undefined
    at ?player=1&number=:47

Comment: I just added example of working code in answer

Answer (score 2):

you just use ajax method of js

```
function r_submit() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "https://www.THIS IS MY URL.php", true);
var params = {"player":document.getElementById("player").value};
xhttp.send(params);
xhttp.onload = function() {
    alert(xhttp.responseText);
}
}
```

and execute r_submit() function button when you click button

here your html code will be like

```
 <div class="border-little text-center grey">
                <input name="player" id="player" value="1" class="hidden">
                <label for="number">Enter a number</label>
                <input type="text" id="number" name="number" placeholder="">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit='r_submit()'>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: I am sorry it doesn't work @manan5439 maybe can you give me more details about what were you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

i've written years ago a simple js part, that allows you to send XHR requests easily. it's a little deprecated but it is a simple template to understand how you CAN go on.
you could modernize it by using webworkers and make it closer to your setup. if you wish i could post an old prototype in JS from me with webworkers and so on (but some names of variables are in german..)

```
function getElement(inp)
{
    return document.getElementById(inp);
}

function put(data,div)
{
    getElement(div).innerHTML = data;
}

//information: autoput means: do you wish to write the raw response in a div? [0,1] - when 1 then put the id of the div in var div at the call of the function
function get(url,data,method,autoput,div)
{
    var req;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    req.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200)
        {
            if(autoput == 1)
            {
                put(req.responseText, div);
            }
        }
    }

    if(method.toLowerCase() == "get")
    {
        req.open("GET",url+data,true);
        req.send();
    }
    else
    {
        if(method.toLowerCase() == "post")
        {
            if(data !== "")
            {
                req.open("POST", url, true);
                req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                req.send(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use iframe technique when jQuery is forbidden. Submit the form to the named iframe and wait for onload event. Modified html and js code will look like:

```
<div class="border-little text-center grey">
    <form action="https://www.THIS IS MY URL.php" method="get" target="myframe">
        <input name="player" id="player" value="1" class="hidden">
        <label for="number">Enter a number</label>
        <input type="text" id="number" name="number" placeholder="">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
<iframe id="myframe" name="myframe"></iframe>


<script>
    var myframe = document.getElementById("myframe");
    myframe.onload = function() {
        var iframeDocument = myframe.contentDocument || myframe.contentWindow.document; // get access to DOM inside the iframe
        var content = iframeDocument.textContent || iframeDocument.body.textContent; // get text of iframe
        var json = JSON.parse(content);

        if (json && json.guess) {
            // process the json here
            alert(json.guess);
        }
    }
</script>
```